# Terraform Azure Container Instance Dynamic Volume - share_name loop over azurerm_storage_share

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following terraform code creating azure storage file shares.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "jms-sftp-share" {
  for_each             = toset(["one", "two", "three"])
  name                 = each.key
  quota                = 5120
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.working-storage_account.name

  acl {
    id = "${each.key}_this_is_my_id"

    access_policy {
      permissions = "rwl"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to then create an azurerm_container_instance with a dynamic volume block that gets it's share name by looping over the azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share.

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "jms-sftp" {
  dns_name_label = "doccji-dts-dev-jms-sftp"
  exposed_port = [
    {
      port     = 22
      protocol = "TCP"
    },
  ]
  location            = var.resource-location
  name                = "${local.resource-name-prefix}-sftp-1"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  resource_group_name = local.resource-group-name
  restart_policy      = "Always"
  tags                = merge(local.common_tags, tomap({ "type" = "docker-sftp-server" }))

  container {
    commands = []
    cpu      = 1
    image    = "atmoz/sftp:latest"
    memory   = 1.5
    name     = "jms-sftp-1"

    ports {
      port     = 22
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
    dynamic "volume" {
      for_each = [for v in azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share : {
        name = v.name
      }]
      content {
        empty_dir            = false
        mount_path           = "/home/${volume.value.name}"
        name                 = "${volume.value.name}-home-folder"
        read_only            = false
        share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name]
        storage_account_key  = azurerm_storage_account.working-storage_account.primary_access_key
        storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.working-storage_account.name
      }

    }
    volume {
      empty_dir            = false
      mount_path           = "/etc/sftp"
      name                 = "sftp-users-conf"
      read_only            = true
      share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-users-share.name
      storage_account_key  = azurerm_storage_account.working-storage_account.primary_access_key
      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.working-storage_account.name
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share,
    azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-users-share
  ]
}
```

I'm stuck on the following error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on container-instance.tf line 36, in resource "azurerm_container_group" "jms-sftp":
  36:         share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share is object with 3 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "share_name": string required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on container-instance.tf line 36, in resource "azurerm_container_group" "jms-sftp":
  36:         share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share is object with 3 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "share_name": string required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on container-instance.tf line 36, in resource "azurerm_container_group" "jms-sftp":
  36:         share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share is object with 3 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "share_name": string required.
```

I believe I get what it's telling me, but I don't know how to setup the

```
share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name]
```

to correctly reference the associated share.

If I change the share_name to be

```
share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name.name]
```

I get output that suggests my previous notation was correct, but I'm just not sure where to go.

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on container-instance.tf line 36, in resource "azurerm_container_group" "jms-sftp":
  36:         share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name.name]
    |----------------
    | volume.value.name is "one"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on container-instance.tf line 36, in resource "azurerm_container_group" "jms-sftp":
  36:         share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name.name]
    |----------------
    | volume.value.name is "two"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on container-instance.tf line 36, in resource "azurerm_container_group" "jms-sftp":
  36:         share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name.name]
    |----------------
    | volume.value.name is "three"

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the specific value in the exported resource attribute object. The error message states:

> azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share is object with 3 attributes

indicating you need to reference the specific element in the object. The three attributes are denoted with the `one` `two` and `three` Strings you use as keys to iterate over in the question. You then access the specific element like:

```
share_name = azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share["one"].name
```

which accesses the `one` element of the `azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-users-share` object from the exported resource attributes.

Comment: I knew that was what I was missing but I couldn't for the life of me come up with how to reference it. You got me where I needed to be.
This ends up being my line, and it seems to work.

azurerm_storage_share.jms-sftp-share[volume.value.name].name